# Parsing an ontology in Python using owlready2 and Google Collab

Tags: sparql, owl, xml-namespaces, ontology, owlready

I have an ontology in an 'owl' file (quran_data_full.owl) and I saved it in a folder in my google drive (Quran Corpus). I want now to perform some queries in this ontology and this is my first time using the ontology file. So I searched on the web and tried to write this code:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus")
go = get_ontology("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl").load()
obo = get_namespace("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/")
d = list(default_world.sparql("""
           SELECT Distinct ?verse ?text  ?word1 ?wordText1 
WHERE { 
?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
?verse rdfs:label ?textSimple.
?verse qur:DisplayText ?text.
?word1 qur:IsPartOf ?verse.
?word1 rdfs:label ?wordText1.
?word1 qur:WordLemma ?wordLema1.
?word1 qur:WordRoot ?wordRoot1.
FILTER(?wordText1 = "الوصية"@ar || ?wordLema1 = "الوصية"@ar || ?wordRoot1 = "الوصية"@ar)
}
LIMIT 25
    """))
```

This gave me this error:
 `ValueError: Undefined prefix 'qur:'!`

The quran_data_full.owl start with these tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY dcterms "http://purl.org/dc/terms/" >
    <!ENTITY foaf "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" >
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY swrl "http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#" >
    <!ENTITY swrlb "http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY qur "http://quranontology.com/Resource/" >
    <!ENTITY skos "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY ace_lexicon "http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/ace_lexicon#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY protege "http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#" >
    <!ENTITY xsp "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#" >
]>



<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://quranontology.com/Resource/"
     xml:base="http://quranontology.com/Resource/"
     xmlns:protege="http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
     xmlns:xsp="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#"
     xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
     xmlns:qur="http://quranontology.com/Resource/"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://quranontology.com/Resource/">
        <dcterms:contributor rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Aimad Hakkoum</dcterms:contributor>
        <dcterms:description xml:lang="en">The Quran ontologies provides elements to describe the content of the quran.</dcterms:description>
        <dcterms:title xml:lang="en">The Quran ontology</dcterms:title>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">version 1.0 :
            Concept definded: Chapter, Verse, Word, Pronoun reference, topic , Location, Living Creation.
      </rdfs:comment>
        <dcterms:creator rdf:resource="http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aimad_Hakkoum2"/>
    </owl:Ontology>
```

You can see the full content of quran_data_full.owl file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xLMYASvHkJt1aoVqxG7A7tpbA6RX6nok/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out the cause of the error.
I should add the prefix in the query.

```
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus")
go = get_ontology("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl").load()
obo = get_namespace("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/")
d = list(default_world.sparql("""
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX qur: <http://quranontology.com/Resource/>
SELECT Distinct ?verse ?text  ?word1 ?wordText1 
WHERE { 
?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
?verse rdfs:label ?textSimple.
?verse qur:DisplayText ?text.
?word1 qur:IsPartOf ?verse.
?word1 rdfs:label ?wordText1.
?word1 qur:WordLemma ?wordLema1.
?word1 qur:WordRoot ?wordRoot1.
FILTER(?wordText1 = "الوصية"@ar || ?wordLema1 = "الوصية"@ar || ?wordRoot1 = "الوصية"@ar)
}
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Owlready automatically generates a prefix based on the last segment of the ontology IRI, excluding the .owl extension. In your case, the ontology can be associated with the `quran_data_full:` prefix (check your ontology IRI).